# Convert day of year value to date in Powershell

Tags: powershell

In Powershell, converting a date into a day of the year value is easy:

```
$DayOfYear = (Get-Date).DayofYear
Write-Host $DayOfYear
140
```

Is there a similar way to convert the day of year back into a date (i.e. 140 = 05/20/2013)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this:

```
([datetime]"01/01/$((Get-Date).Year)").AddDays(140-1)

20. mai 2013 00:00:00
```

mai = may in norwegian :-)

Comment: Perfect! I just added a 2nd step to get the short date:
$TempDate = ([datetime]"01/01/$((Get-Date).Year)").AddDays(140-1)
$ShortDate = $TempDate.ToShortDateString()
Write-Host $ShortDate
05/20/2013

Comment: @W.J.P. that's exactly what I did :)

Answer (score 2):

You could create a DateTime object representing the start of the year, then add the number of days to it, e.g.:

```
(New-Object System.DateTime 2013,1,1).AddDays(140-1)
```

Comment: Thanks. This also works if I initialize a 2nd variable to get the current year - i.e. $CurrentYear = (Get-Date).Year then convert the output to a short date.

Answer (score 1):

This might be helpful for you:

```
$startdate_year = ([datetime]"01/01/$((Get-Date).Year)")
$a = (Get-Date $startdate_year).AddDays(139)
"Date: " + $a.ToShortDateString()
```

Now you will get the result like this:

```
Date: 5/20/2013
```

Comment: @Graimer yup... +1 for your answer :)

Answer (score -1):

Use this method to avoid [datetime] objects and use Powershell syntax only:

```
$DayOfYear = (Get-Date).DayOfYear
$Today = (Get-Date -Month 1 -Day 1).AddDays($DayOfYear-1)
"$($Today.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy")) is day $DayOfYear of 365"
```

Output:

```
10/03/2017 is day 276 of 365
```

Comment: please add some description. may some one will not understand pure code

Comment: Please provide more explanation. Code-only answers are often confusing and not very helpful to somebody who comes looking for this solution in the future.